# How to set all pages of a subdomain to redirect to a single page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Let's say my domain name is **website123.com** and I have a subdomain of **my.website123.com**

I've deleted the "my" subdomain from the site and want to make sure that anyone that goes to any page with a my.website123.com URL is redirected to the main www.website123.com URL.  The "my" subdomain has a ton of pages of it, so I need to make sure that regardless of which page a user goes to on the "my" subdomain, that they're redirected to the site's main index page.

I was thinking to get this accomplished through .htaccess - is that the best way?  If yes how?

Comment: If you've deleted the domain, does that mean the server no longer accepts requests for **my.website123.com**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@joeh0717

Yes, for an .htaccess file modify it to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.domain.com
    RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Note that this code has to be in the root directory of your subdomain. If, as you mentioned before, you've deleted this subdomain, you're going to need to re-establish it and put this .htaccess file in the root.

Comment: This didn't work to me, I will post what worked to me as a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct method if you wish to redirect all the pages and directories after that too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} nz.business2sell.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.business2sell.co.nz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For example, `nz.business2sell.com/businesses/` or `nz.business2sell.com/broker_directory/` 
both redirects to `www.business2sell.co.nz/businesses/` or `/broker_directory/`

This way no more pages are left behind

Comment: This is not what was requested: all pages from deleted subdomain must be redirected TO THE SITE'S MAIN INDEX PAGE.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache configuration directly is always preferred over .htaccess. Do you have access to that?

And do you want to redirect all users from the former subdomain to the index page of the main domain, or are you looking to map them page by page (for example my.domain.com/contact/ to www.domain.com/contact)?

Comment: I have access to WHM and cPanel and I'm running on an Apache VPS, so I'm sure I have access to what you'd require me to (I just might have never accessed whatever I need to before, so I might need directions).  I'm just trying to redirect all users from the former subdomain (regardless of URL), to the site's main www index page (not map them page by page).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is go to the httpd.conf file and add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

That will point all pages from the subdomain at your main domain.

Good luck!

Comment: Question - will the coding you've provided also work in .htaccess?  O does it have to be modified?  I know that you're saying httpd.conf is preferable, but I'm just curious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked to me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} deleted_subdomain.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```