# Redirect all pages from domain to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Any idea about how to redirect all pages from my main domain to subdomain

- www.domain.com/page1  ---> sub.domain.com/page1;
- www.domain.com/page2  ---> sub.domain.com/page2 etc.

Thank you

Comment: I think this will help u 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721334/how-to-set-all-pages-of-a-subdomain-to-redirect-to-a-single-page

Comment: thank you, I do not want to set all pages to redirect to a single page... my target is to set domain.com/oldpage to sub.domain.com/oldpage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net you can just use Redirect("http://sub.domain.com/page1");